# Docker Compose Volume Mounting Issue on Windows (WSL2): "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I'm encountering an issue while trying to mount folders from my host machine to docker volumes on Windows (WSL2) using Docker Desktop for Windows (Windows 11). The project runs smoothly on MacOS, but I'm facing challenges getting it to work on Windows.

**Details:**

Docker Desktop Version: `4.26.1 (131620)`, Engine Version: `24.0.7`
Project Structure: Multiple Docker projects (images) and a Composer project in the same directory. The Composer project orchestrates the startup of these projects.

**Error:**

When attempting to run docker compose up in the Composer project, I encounter the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount /home/user/projects/composer/docker-volumes/local-mongo-data:/var/lib/docker/volumes/composer_local-mongo-data/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
```

**Observations:**

- The directories inside `composer/docker-volumes` do exist, and I can navigate to them successfully.
- I've tried eliminating the use of `$PWD` and manually setting directories like `/home/user/projects/composer/docker-volumes/local-mongo-data` or `./docker-volumes/local-mongo-data`.
- Permissions for the directories are set to `777`.

**Docker Compose Snippet:**

Here's a snippet of the relevant part of the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
# ... (other services)

volumes:
  local-rabbit-data:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/docker-volumes/local-rabbit-data
      o: bind
  local-mongo-data:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/docker-volumes/local-mongo-data
      o: bind
  local-redis-data:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/docker-volumes/local-redis-data
      o: bind
```

**Directory Structure:**

- Projects on Ubuntu (WSL): `/home/user/projects`
- Composer Project's volume directory:
  `/home/user/projects/composer/docker-volumes`

**Request for Assistance:**

I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly set the directories for volumes in this Windows (WSL2) environment. Despite trying various solutions, the issue persists. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!